# How to read <br> tags from database to angularJS view

Tags: html, angularjs

I would like to convert **br** that is saved from the database to newline on my front-end.
Here's what I got so far:

```
<div ng-repeat="desc in items.description.split(',')"><span class="pre-break">{{desc}}</span></div>
```

CSS:

```
.pre-break{
     white-space: pre-wrap !important;
}
```

Sample data from Database:

```
6 pcs <br/> 2 pc thigh, 2 pc wing, 2 pc chops
```

But the result is still like this:

```
6 pcs <br/> 2 pc thigh | 2 pc wing | 2 pc chops
```

What will I do to convert the br tag?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[ng-bind-html](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)** like

```
<div ng-repeat="desc in items.description.split(',')">
    <span class="pre-break">
        <p ng-bind-html="desc"></p>
    </span>
</div>
```